# Get list of fields with decorator

Tags: typescript, angular5, typescript-decorator

I create my decorator

```
export function Id(target: any, key: string) { ... }
```

put it on fields

```
Class Test {
     @Id public id: int;
}
```

How Can I get lists of field with decorator (@Id)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use target then set key in use custom property (eg: __ pros __ )

```
function myDecorator(target: any, key: string) {

  if (!target.__pros__) {
    target.__pros__ = []
  }
  target.__pros__.push(key);

}

Class A {
     @myDecorator name: string;
}

const obj = new A();
console.log("field with decorator on : ", a["__pros__"]);
```

console output :

> ["name"]